# Google Search API sometimes reurns first result sometimes second result compared to web interface

Tags: javascript, api, search

Firstly this is not a duplicate of: [Why does a google search through the google api return different results to a search in the web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654546/why-does-a-google-search-through-the-google-api-return-different-results-to-a-se) Nor any of the other "google search API returning unexpected results" questions that I have been able to find.

I am writing a small javascript program which uses the Google websearch API. I am creating custom links for my where to buy page which are supposed to direct the user to the correct page on our dealers site to buy the product they were last viewing when they clicked "where to buy". I use the javascript method of **document.referrer** then parse the URL to determine which page on my site the user last visited.

I then create a appropriate query string, restrict the site to the particular dealer, tell google to only return one result then run the query. I then use the URL to rewrite the HTML in that particular div href to the first (and only) search result. I am essentially emulating the functions of the "I'm feeling lucky" button Google used to have, but structuring the query in such a way that I get exactly the result I'm looking for.

OK, so now that you know what I'm doing and why I'm doing it, here is where things get weird: Most of the results I get work perfectly. They return the first search result. Some of them (and its always the same ones) return the second search result.

Here is the code you can copy and paste into the [Code Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/) yourself to see the issue I am referring too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <title>Google AJAX Search API Sample</title>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyA5m1Nc8ws2BbmPRwKu5gFradvD_hgq6G0" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
google.load('search', '1');   
var SearchVariables = [
      ["alto","altomusic.com","http://www.earthworksaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/altomusic-button.png","wp-image-6343"],
      ["acme","www.acmelectronics.com","http://www.earthworksaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/acme-button.png","wp-image-6344"],
      ["bhphoto","www.bhphotovideo.com","http://www.earthworksaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/bh-button3.png","wp-image-6345"],
      ["frontend","www.frontendaudio.com","http://www.earthworksaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/frontend-button.png","wp-image-6346"],
      ["fullcompass","www.fullcompass.com","http://www.earthworksaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/fullcompass-button3.png","wp-image-6347"],
      ["performance","www.performanceaudio.com","http://www.earthworksaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/performance-audio-button.png","wp-image-6348"],
      ["proaudio","www.proaudiosuperstore.com","http://www.earthworksaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/ProAudioSolutions-button.png","wp-image-6349"],
      ["rmc","www.rmcaudiodirect.com","http://www.earthworksaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/rmc-button1.png","wp-image-6350"],
      ["sweetwater","www.sweetwater.com","http://www.earthworksaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/sweetwater-button3.png","wp-image-6351"],
      ["vintageking","www.vintageking.com","http://www.earthworksaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/vintageking-button3.png","wp-image-6352"]
    ];  
var Search = new Array(SearchVariables.length);
function searchComplete() {


  for(var i = 0; i < Search.length; i++){
    if (Search[i].results && Search[i].results.length > 0) {
       var contentDiv = document.getElementById(Search[i].ed[0]);
       var curURL = Search[i].results[0].unescapedUrl;
       var newImage = ' <a href="'+curURL+'"><img class="alignleft size-full '+Search[i].ed[2]+'" title="'+Search[i].ed[0]+'" src="'+Search[i].ed[1]+'" alt=" " width="235" height="94" /></a>';
       contentDiv.innerHTML = newImage;
    }
  }     
} 
function parseURLString(inString)
{
    var OutString = 'earthworks';
        inString = inString.replace(/-/g,' ');
        inString = inString.replace('zdt','');
    var MicVsPre=['preamps','microphones'];
    var idx = [];
        for(var j=0;j<MicVsPre.length;j++)
        {
          if(inString.search(MicVsPre[j])>=0)
          {
            OutString = OutString+' '+MicVsPre[j];
                  for(var i=inString.length;i>0;i--)
                  {
                    if(inString[i]=='/')
                    {
                      idx.push(i);
                    }
                  }
            OutString = OutString+' '+inString.substring(idx[0],idx[1]+1);
          }
        }
return OutString;
}

function OnLoad() {
      var String_To_Parse = 'http://www.earthworksaudio.com/microphones/qtc-series-2/qtc40/';     
      var query = parseURLString(String_To_Parse);

       var testloc = document.getElementById('vardiv');
       testloc.innerHTML = query;

      for(var i = 0; i < SearchVariables.length; i++)
      {
        Search[i] = new google.search.WebSearch();
        Search[i].setNoHtmlGeneration();
        Search[i].setResultSetSize(1);
        Search[i].setUserDefinedLabel([SearchVariables[i][0],SearchVariables[i][2],SearchVariables[i][3]]);
        Search[i].setSiteRestriction(SearchVariables[i][1]);
        Search[i].setSearchCompleteCallback(this, searchComplete,null);
        Search[i].execute(query);
      }
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="vardiv">Testing</div>
    <div id='acme'></div>
    <div id='alto'></div>
    <div id='bhphoto'></div>
    <div id='fullcompass'></div>
    <div id='frontend'></div>
    <div id='performance'></div>
    <div id='proaudio'></div>
    <div id='rmc'></div>
    <div id='sweetwater'></div>
    <div id='vintageking'></div>
  </body>
</html>​
```

I have included a sample product page URL instead of actually using the **document.referrer** method (since obviously you are not navigating my website right now) to demonstrate whats going on. I have also created a extra div tag at the top which shows what the exact search that is being performed.

Notice how the last one on the list (vintage king, or fourth to last in proaudio soltuions) both pull down the URL for the **SECOND** search result if you do the exact same search yourself. However most of them correctly pull down the **FIRST** search result (for example: sweetwater, b&h, full compass). This happens with almost every single search I do on those particular sites. I know that this is not related to anything to do with my browser, and my stored settings since I have tried this incognito, on other computers, in different browsers etc. Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? Why cant I always get the first search result from the web based Google search to be the returned URL?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the websearch api?  It's been deprecated for years...

Comment: I am aware of its status, but according to google it is supposed to continue to function for the foreseeable future with the only limitation being on requests per day, and there will be no updates too it that could break the functionality of my program. Given the simple nature of what I am using it for, I see no issues that would make me want to move to their custom search API since it is harder to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Comment: Hmm... I'm more familiar with the CSE api, but it probably still stems from the same issues as the other question you cited: maybe the detected locale is different, maybe other parameters have different defaults, maybe the API isn't exactly the same as the one google uses for its web results (it is, after all, a deprecated api; perhaps google results go through some other processing elsewhere)

Comment: Also in general, search APIs will give similar but different results at different times to different people. It might be easier to just rethink your approach to the problem. If you need to do things this way, using the mobile endpoint and parsing the HTML (I know it sucks -- I had to do it once for gmail) might be the only way.

Comment: Well if it wasn't this specific an "issue" and its exactly the same thing every single time. Its always search result #2, and its always when searching exactly those dealers websites, AND its always the second best result? You are absolutely correct about one thing tho, if its an API thing and there are "issues" with that API I never could fix it. I was hoping someone would be able to tell me what is wrong with my specific code that they could see. What I was really looking for was some parameter which would disable "optimizations" that might be breaking the search.

Comment: There might be one I'm not aware of; google's search APIs are not very complete/accessible.

Comment: You can say that again. Some of the tricks I used here for passing variables to my callback function I was only able to figure out by using firebug and examining my DOM to determine what variables I was setting. The documentation was not very complete at all. I wish there was some method I could override to fix this in the API tho, that would make me one happy coder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had that problem when I was doing something similar, and according to what I found back then (iirc) returned results depend on the language parameters you pass to google and the browser ID string.

Note that this could have changed, and it's a long shot, but it's worth checking.

EDIT:

I just saw you're looking for some kind of proof for the answer, so here you go:
http://www.windmeadow.com/node/36 <-- Google gives different search results based on browser.
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/7K02-AUCTVM <-- Different search results with different languages

EDIT 2:

It's a know bug in Googles AJAX API: http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=43

Comment: If this were the problem, I would think adding Search[i].setRestriction(google.search.Search.RESTRICT_EXTENDED_ARGS,{ "lr" : "lang_en" , "gl" : "us" , "cr" : "countryUS" , "filter" : "1" }); to the searcher object would be the best first step to solving it. But this seems to just return the same results. Got any ideas how I can undo this "bias" google applies? The thing that I find most vexing about this is that it is ALWAYS the second search result returned, and it would NEVER be the best result for the query in question.

Comment: According to this http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24783/why-do-different-browsers-return-different-search-results-at-google-and-how-can you could try to remove cookies. Also, try to search in plain ascii (just for the test) in order to be completely sure that Google isn't doing anything `weird`.

Comment: Cookies are interesting, but you know the one thing for me is this: Its always the second result, (which is always inferior to the first search result that should be returned) and its always the same URLs it returns the second result from. I would believe if this were not such an amazingly surgical search (I mean literally I am precisely looking for ONE page, on ONE website where I know the base URL of said site and every other keywords that will reside there in to give me the ONE correct search result). I will give you the bounty if I don't get a better answer in the next two days...

Comment: By the way, is the first result related to the query in any way? Is it from the same base url (as in the same website)?

Comment: Have you tried running the code I posted above? I restrict every search to a single URL as specified in the variable: SearchVariables, column 2. And all I'm doing is looking for our specific product page on a given dealers site. So every given search is from the same base URL. Thats whats so confusing about this issue...

Comment: I just found this... According to http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=43 this is a known bug (and looking at the report date I really don't think it will be fixed ever)

Comment: Thanks Alex, it looks like you are right.... Its very unfortunate that google messes up its own API this much, seemingly intentionally to limit people from using the API's and loading down their servers I guess? Its really a shame because I really do love googles services in general. I have marked your response as the answer. I would edit your original response and include this last link so its clear to anyone else who stumbles across my query that this is just an endemic problem with the google API.