# ruby on rails google-search gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

my problem is that, I'm trying to check a text area content against the web looking for palgiarized content. So my high level solution for this is to get the content of the text area, enclose them in "double quotes" and do a search in google. And I want to return the top 5 sites that are returned by google.

In order to apply that pseudo code on my app, I installed gem google-search, but when I tried to run my string, the sites returned by the gem have missing items take for example the search "EVE Search - Heavy dict defence?", if you run it on google, it'll return 1 site. But on my app, it doesn't return anything.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe accessing search from google's API is different than accessing it from your browser. Google returns its search results dynamically based on things likes browser history, your local cache and cookies, etc. Even if you searched for "EVE Search - Heavy dict defence?" from two different browsers, your results could vary.

Also, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/654558/1481644

Answer (score 0):

You can go with ruby web-search gem..........it will take a query string to search and return the sites and for more info check here https://github.com/mattetti/ruby-web-search